# Using the reults of multiple for loops to post a single json response

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops, python-requests, yaml

Okay, so this is a loaded question but and I'm sure theres an easy method to use here, but I'm stuck.

Long story short, I am tasked with creating a function in python (to be run an AWS lambda) which can perform acceptance tests on a series of URL's using `python-requests`. These requests will be used to assert the HTTP response codes and a custom HTTP header identifying if an `haproxy` backend is correct.

The URL's themselves will be maintained in a `yaml` document which will be converted to a `dict` in python and passed to a for loop which will use `python requests` to `HTTP GET` the response code and header of the URL.

The issue I am having is getting a single `body` object to return the results of multiple `for` loops.

I have tried to find similar use cases but cannot

```py
import requests
import json
import yaml


def acc_tests():

    with open("test.yaml", 'r') as stream:
        testurls = yaml.safe_load(stream)

    results = {}
    # endpoint/path 1
    for url in testurls["health endpoints"]:
        r = requests.get(url, params="none")
        stat = r.status_code
        result = json.dumps(print(url, stat))
        results = json.dumps(result)

    # endpoint path  with headers
    for url in testurls["xtvapi"]:
        headers = {'H': 'xtvapi.cloudtv.comcast.net'}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params="none")
        stat = r.status_code
        head = r.headers["X-FINITY-TANGO-BACKEND"]
        result = json.dumps((url, stat, head))
        results = json.dumps(result)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(results)
    }


acc_tests()
```

YAML file:

```
health endpoints:
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-east-1-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/tango-health/
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-east-1-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-east-2-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/tango-health/
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-east-2-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-west-2-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/tango-health/
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-west-2-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/

xtvapi:
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-east-1-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-east-2-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/
  - https://xfinityapi-tango-production-aws-us-west-2-active.r53.aae.comcast.net/
```

What I think is happening is that both `for` loops are running one after another, but the value of `results` is empty, but I'm not sure what to do in order to update/append the `results` dict with the results of each loop.

Comment: Can you post a sample url from `testurls["health endpoints"]` and one from `testurls["xtvapi"]`?

Comment: In each iteration of your `for` loop, you are overwriting it with `json.dumps(result)`. Therefore in the end, `results` only contain the last result.

Comment: @JackFleeting here is a .yaml file that should work. these url's are publicly accessible

Comment: @dashmug I understand what you mean, but I'm not sure of any alternative. To my knowledge `dictionary.update` will only _update_ existing values for existing keys. What would be a good way to append to the dictionary? Is it worth just using a list instead? Keep in mind that the `return` function's `body` needs to be in valid json for the aws lambda to return it in the HTTP response.

Comment: Assuming you only had the first url from `health endpoints` and the first url from `xtvapi` to work with - what would `body` look like exactly?

Comment: @JaredMiller You are right about `dictionary.update` but you are not using it in the above code. You are redefining `result` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks. I ended up solving this by creating a `dict` with immutable keys for each test type and then using `append` to add the results to a nested list within the dict.

Here is the "working" code as it is in the AWS Lambda function:

```py
from botocore.vendored import requests
import json
import yaml

def acc_tests(event, context):

    with open("test.yaml", 'r') as stream:
        testurls = yaml.safe_load(stream)

    results = {'tango-health': [], 'xtvapi': []}

    # Tango Health
    for url in testurls["health endpoints"]:
        r = requests.get(url, params="none")
        result = url, r.status_code
        assert r.status_code == 200
        results["tango-health"].append(result)

    # xtvapi default/cloudtv
    for url in testurls["xtvapi"]:
        headers = {'H': 'xtvapi.cloudtv.comcast.net'}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params="none")
        result = url, r.status_code, r.headers["X-FINITY-TANGO-BACKEND"]
        assert r.status_code == 200
        assert r.headers["X-FINITY-TANGO-BACKEND"] == "tango-big"
        results["xtvapi"].append(result)

    resbody = json.dumps(results)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': resbody
    }
```